# Cloud functions "call" API limit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I wanted to get the server time form firebase and as a lot of answers suggest writing to the firestore and then using Timestamp field is not an option.

I was thinking of writing a cloud function to get the server time, however I checked the limits and quotas documentation and it mentions 16 invocations in 100 seconds.

[Quotas and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas)

> API calls (CALL)  Calls to the "call" API 16 per 100 seconds

Does this mean from my app I cannot call a callable function more than 16 times per 100 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're misinterpreting that table.  The rate limit you're looking for is the first row:

> Function invocations per second - The number of function invocations
>   in a second. If exceeded, all functions will be paused until the next
>   quota period
>
> 100,000,000 per 100 seconds

The Call API is something different.

Comment: oh ok. I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: @Doug So how to understand "Call API"?