# Firebase Cloud Function:How many concurrent invocations a single HTTP trigger type function can have at any given time?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

From the doc in "Rate Limit" section, calls are restricted to 16 invocations per 100 seconds. But I am not sure if it is saying about onRequest/onCall HTTP triggers. That limit seems to be related to some  CLI deployment or "testing via Firebase Console" (whatever that means) and not a call from client mobile sdk. If the restriction is legitimate, then that seems too limiting for something that is advertised to scale to potentially "millions/billions". I have a use case where 500 or so mobile users will be calling an HTTP end point which will perform a mixture of read/write to Firestore + some processing at a moment notice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloud functions "call" API limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756272/cloud-functions-call-api-limit)

Comment: @Jay, thanks for the comment. But I am afraid not. I have already browsed through that and similar answers on this site. Here is an extract from the could function doc:"Insufficient quota generally occurs if you mistakenly use this API to invoke your functions in production". That extract is for the "callAPI" mentioned in the answer you provided. As you see, it is very confusing and somewhat contradictory to say the least. The testing on my side I did just now doesn't really hold up to the limit as well.

Comment: Oh. I see what you mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "rate limits" table [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas) mentions 16 invocations per 100 seconds, but the table is actually referring to usage limits on invoking the `Cloud functions API` to list/deploy cloud functions in a firebase project. Not invocation limits on the actual cloud fuctions which are much more generous.

The rate limits for `background` functions such as firebase event handlers (onCreate, onUpdate, etc) or PubSub scheduled functions, etc are 3000 concurrent invocations (for a function that takes 100 seconds to execute).

The rate limits for HTTP onCall functions are unlimited, at the moment. They simply scale up to accommodate higher traffic.

> Background functions have additional limits, as explained below. These limits do not apply to HTTP functions

Here's a screenshot from [cloud functions quota page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com&usage=ALL&project=_)

[image]

Comment: Awesome!! That is more like it. They way they liberally use the term "call API" is what causes the confusion. It would be nice to make a clear distinction in the doc, I guess...

Comment: @AungKhant @ Jay, What happens if we invoke a background function more than the limit. Is it going to fail for extra requests? Or queued up and take it in the next batch?

Comment: @JayCodist But it says 3000 max concurrent invocations, right? So what does it means?

Comment: Oh Sorry! With respect to background functions, extra calls will queue up

Comment: @AadityaPaliwal if you go over that limit, the extra invocations will be queued and those will have to wait until 100 secs.